# For small x, Taylor Series to determine constants n and C in the approximation

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, approximation

cos(x) - e^(-(x^2)/2)

I have tried writing the taylor expansion for cosine and e but do not know how to combine them in one. In addition to this, i do not know how to approach the problem whilst determining n and C.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: A Taylor expansion is about determining a series, which is a polynomial of infinite degree. Usual addition rules for polynomials apply.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Just as you did, start with the basic series $$\cos(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}$$ and $$e^{-y}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}y^n$$ In the second one, replace $y$ by $\frac{x^2}{2}$ and now combine them for your expression.